# Find Login and Logout pair from logs base on log type

Tags: sql, sql-server

Event Logs table receives logs from each computer whenever user logs in and similarly whenever users logs out.
I need to find login and logout pair/row. It essentially looks at the computer Id and checks does it have login types(40,43,44,53,57 ) and find first login then the corresponding logout(42,45,52)
Also list the rows that don't have logout events found yet like logout time would null or insert into a variable table to keep track to display at the end. Because when user logs in only login(40,43,44,53,57 ) logs are received, which means user is logged in until next logout(42,45,52) is received.
The current code I have does find somewhat login and logouts but does not show the orphan(not corresponding logout found) rows:

```
Login  types are  40,43,44,53,57  
Logout types are  42,45,52
```

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventLogs](
    [ComputerId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, 
    [EventDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [EventType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL     
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample data

```
INSERT [dbo].[EventLogs] ([ComputerId], [EventDateTime], [EventType], [UserId]) VALUES (N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:37:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), 42, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1') 
INSERT [dbo].[EventLogs] ([ComputerId], [EventDateTime], [EventType], [UserId]) VALUES (N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:00:54.0000000' AS DateTime2), 43, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1')
INSERT [dbo].[EventLogs] ([ComputerId], [EventDateTime], [EventType], [UserId]) VALUES (N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:00:54.0000000' AS DateTime2), 53, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1')
INSERT [dbo].[EventLogs] ([ComputerId], [EventDateTime], [EventType], [UserId]) VALUES (N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:37:41.0000000' AS DateTime2), 43, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1')
INSERT [dbo].[EventLogs] ([ComputerId], [EventDateTime], [EventType], [UserId]) VALUES (N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:37:41.0000000' AS DateTime2), 53, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1')
```

Below is orphan login

```
INSERT [dbo].[EventLogs] ([ComputerId], [EventDateTime], [EventType], [UserId]) VALUES (N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:49:50.0000000' AS DateTime2), 53, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1')
INSERT [dbo].[EventLogs] ([ComputerId], [EventDateTime], [EventType], [UserId]) VALUES (N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:49:50.0000000' AS DateTime2), 43, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1')
INSERT [dbo].[EventLogs] ([ComputerId], [EventDateTime], [EventType], [UserId]) VALUES (N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:49:54.0000000' AS DateTime2), 44, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1')
```

The current code:

```
    DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME= CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR,( Select CAST(Min(EventDateTime)as date) from dbo.EventLogs )) + ' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, '00:00:01'))
    DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME= GETUTCDATE()
    
    DECLARE @Events table (ComputerId uniqueidentifier ,UserId uniqueidentifier,EventDateTime DateTime2,EventType   int);
    Insert into @Events (ComputerId,UserId,EventDateTime,EventType) 
    select  
    eventlogs.ComputerId,
    eventlogs.UserId as UserId ,
    eventlogs.EventDateTime,
    eventlogs.EventType       
    from  dbo.EventLogs as eventlogs  
        where (EventDateTime> @StartDate and EventDateTime<@EndDate) and EventType in (52, 57, 53, 42, 41, 40, 43, 44, 45)    
             
    SELECT
        dt.LoginTime, 
        dt.LogoutTime,
        dt.UserId,
        dt.ComputerId 
        FROM (
                SELECT
                    p.ComputerId as ComputerId,
                    p.UserId as UserId,
                    p.EventDateTime AS LoginTime,
                    CASE WHEN  c.EventType = 53 or c.EventType = 43 or c.EventType = 44 or c.EventType = 40 or c.EventType = 57
                    THEN NULL 
                    ELSE 
                        c.EventDateTime 
                    END 
                    AS LogoutTime, p.EventDateTime FROM @Events p               
                    left join @Events c ON p.EventDateTime<c.EventDateTime
                    WHERE 
                    (p.EventType=53 or p.EventType=43 or p.EventType = 44 or p.EventType = 40 or c.EventType = 57)
                    AND c.EventDateTime=(SELECT min(EventDateTime) FROM @Events WHERE EventDateTime>p.EventDateTime 
                    AND ComputerId=p.ComputerId AND UserId=p.UserId)
                UNION
                SELECT
                    p.ComputerId as ComputerId,
                    p.UserId as UserId, 
                    NULL AS LoginTime,
                    p.EventDateTime,
                    p.EventDateTime
                    FROM @Events p
                     left JOIN @Events  c ON p.EventDateTime>c.EventDateTime
                    WHERE 
                     c.EventDateTime=(SELECT MAX(EventDateTime) FROM @Events WHERE  EventDateTime<p.EventDateTime 
                     AND ComputerId=p.ComputerId and UserId = p.UserId) 
                     AND (p.EventType = 52 or p.EventType = 42 or p.EventType = 45) 
                     AND (c.EventType = 52 or c.EventType = 42 or c.EventType = 45)             
                ) dt
            where dt.LoginTime is not null and LogoutTime is not null and UserId is not null
```

Result:

[image]

The most important part is that we want to keep track of the events that were processed or that were part of creating login and logouts so that those can be deleted from EventLogs at the end. Because we don't want to go through processed logs again.
User A logged in from Computer A at 2022-12-31 10:00:20 , tables received data like events 53,43. Then user logged out 2022-12-31 11:00:00 and events received like 42,52. So this became a complete login and logout. Now user logs in again 20 seconds later at  2022-12-31 11:00:20.  again events  53,43 recorded in table. So now if we run sql script we will see that there is one login and logout session completed. But events 53,43 received at  2022-12-31 11:00:20 doesn't have logout events yet therefore user is logged in. at this time we want to delete rows from table that were procced and leave these new login events so that it will proceed when SQL script runs again.

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect for your sample data.

Comment: I update the question above and added a screenshot. The most important part is that we want to keep track of the events that were processed or that were part of creating login and logouts so that those can be deleted from EventLogs at the end. Because we don't want to go through processed logs again. Thank you

Comment: THe image you added doesn't appear to relate to the sample data in your question. you need to show what you *do* want, not what you *don't* want

Comment: Does the table have a way of identifying a unique row (primary key or otherwise)? Can you have multiples of the same type e.g., for the same computer/user you have 2 logins then 2 logouts because they openned 2 sessions? More specifically, is there ANY situation where a logout does not correspond to the last login? Sorry - but these questions affect how the answer would be constructed (e.g., if you can have 2 logins then 2 logouts, you need to ensure you match up the logouts to the appropriate logins).

Comment: Yes, the table does have a primary  key for each row.. yes it is possible where logout doesn't correspond to last login. Like in case of multiple users are logged on to a windows server.

Comment: We still need the output according to the posted input data, the shared image does not match the input you shared.

Comment: Yes that's correct. The sample image is from the larger table that I couldn't paste here. I could provide more raw input data if needed Ahmed

Comment: We need to see the output for the input data you post, that is it

Comment: Here are the result for sample data: https://dbfiddle.uk/5ZPJM8pw and if you remove where clause at the end it will show orphan logins

Comment: If your SQL already provides the exact result you want to generate, why did you create this question?  Assuming this isn't the result you want to generate, post the exact result you wish to generate based on the sample data you posted, and explain the logic behind each result row.  The question seems to have excluded important detail.  Don't forget to mention the two nearly identical login rows which refer to the same user/computer/time, but just different login types.  Is there a different logout type for each different login type??

Comment: You currently have (in the non-orphan data) 4 logins and 1 logout.  Explain this.  Did you want to ignore multiple logins for the same user/computer prior to the one logout?  Do the types of logins and the types of logouts really matter in your requirement, or is it acceptable to treat them identically.  For instance, 10 logins followed by one logout just generates one single result.  If no logout is found, do you want to treat those 5 or 10 logins as one login orphan?  **Read carefully and answer each question carefully, in the question.**

Comment: Thanks Jon. The thing I am trying is that when login and logout pairs are created at a given time like when trigger is fired on insert on the table. It is possible , lets say 15 events were used to form login and logouts. Now from a computer user just logged in and until we get logout events for this user we want to keep these events in the table and delete the ones that are proceed .

Comment: I added more details to the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach that finds login edges and ties all rows from one edge to just before the next edge together.  If an edge has no subsequent logout detected (an orphan), that logout column is null.

I'm probably missing a little logic here.  Slightly more varied data would probably expose it.  I'll update the logic shortly. (**Corrected**)

I added some data to the fiddle (a second user) to expose the issue.

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/o-Qxv9zV)

```sql
WITH args (_StartDate, _EndDate) AS (
        SELECT CAST(MIN(EventDateTime) AS date)
             , GETUTCDATE()
          FROM EventLogs
     )
   , _Events0 AS (
        SELECT *
             , CASE WHEN EventType     IN (53, 43, 44, 40, 57) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isLogin
          FROM EventLogs
         WHERE EventType IN (52, 57, 53, 42, 41, 40, 43, 44, 45)
     )
   , _Events1 AS (
        SELECT *
             , CASE WHEN isLogin = 0 OR isLogin = LAG(isLogin) OVER (PARTITION BY ComputerId, UserId ORDER BY EventDateTime, EventType) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS edge
          FROM _Events0
     )
   , _Events AS (
        SELECT eventlogs.ComputerId
             , eventlogs.UserId as UserId
             , eventlogs.EventDateTime
             , eventlogs.EventType
             , SUM(edge) OVER (PARTITION BY ComputerId, UserId ORDER BY EventDateTime, isLogin DESC) AS loginGroup
             , CASE WHEN isLogin = 1 THEN EventDateTime END AS loginTime
             , CASE WHEN isLogin = 0 THEN EventDateTime END AS logoutTime
          FROM _Events1 AS eventlogs, args
         WHERE EventDateTime BETWEEN _StartDate AND _EndDate
     )
SELECT ComputerId, UserId, loginGroup
     , MIN(loginTime)  AS login
     , MAX(logoutTime) AS logout
  FROM _Events
 WHERE loginGroup > 0
 GROUP BY ComputerId, UserId, loginGroup
 ORDER BY ComputerId, UserId, loginGroup
;
```

With your sample data, the following is produced:

| ComputerId | UserId | loginGroup | login | logout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674 | b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1 | 1 | 2022-12-31 00:00:54.0000000 | 2022-12-31 00:37:33.0000000 |
| 060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674 | b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1 | 2 | 2022-12-31 00:37:41.0000000 | null |
| 060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674 | b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a2 | 1 | 2022-12-31 00:00:54.0000000 | 2022-12-31 00:37:33.0000000 |
| 060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674 | b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a2 | 2 | 2022-12-31 00:37:41.0000000 | null |

Comment: Thanks Jon. I processed data using Patrick Hurst answer then fed the data into your script and delete the rest rows. It seems to be working correctly.  Will it cause performance issues on a large data set like couple millions rows?

Comment: Is there a way to make it little faster? it takes almost 10 minutes to process 50000 rows. Thanks

Comment: @Raj Ask another/separate question.  Provide more detail, like the exact SQL, with CREATE TABLE statements, and all existing indexes, plus the explain plan associated with the query in question.  This question doesn't seem to contain the real table(s), nor indexes.

Comment: @Raj Try adding an index on _(ComputerId, UserId, EventDateTime, EventType)_.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example data (and adding a row to demonstrate a second logout):

```
DECLARE @EventLogs TABLE (ComputerId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, EventDateTime DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL, EventType INT NOT NULL, UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL);
INSERT INTO @EventLogs (ComputerId, EventDateTime, EventType, UserId) VALUES 
(N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:37:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), 42, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1'), 
(N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:00:54.0000000' AS DateTime2), 43, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1'),
(N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:00:54.0000000' AS DateTime2), 53, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1'),
(N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:37:41.0000000' AS DateTime2), 43, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1'),
(N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:37:41.0000000' AS DateTime2), 53, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1');

INSERT INTO @EventLogs (ComputerId, EventDateTime, EventType, UserId) VALUES 
(N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:49:50.0000000' AS DateTime2), 53, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1'),
(N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:49:50.0000000' AS DateTime2), 43, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1'),
(N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:49:54.0000000' AS DateTime2), 44, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1');

INSERT INTO @EventLogs (ComputerID, EventDateTime, EventType, UserId) VALUES
(N'060ba6d9-4a58-4186-bb89-369fc56ae674',CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:37:55.0000000' AS DateTime2), 52, N'b2283380-6a52-492b-9617-5d4b202da8a1');

SELECT *, 'These are the original rows'
  FROM @EventLogs;
```

```
ComputerId                              EventDateTime               EventType   UserId                                  (No column name)
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:37:33.0000000 42          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are the original rows
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:00:54.0000000 43          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are the original rows
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:00:54.0000000 53          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are the original rows
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:37:41.0000000 43          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are the original rows
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:37:41.0000000 53          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are the original rows
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:49:50.0000000 53          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are the original rows
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:49:50.0000000 43          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are the original rows
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:49:54.0000000 44          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are the original rows
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:37:55.0000000 52          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are the original rows
```

We can run over the table and determine the completed sessions, assuming the only criteria is that it's the most recent logout type for the same computer/user using a CTE and then DELETE from the table where the rows match:

```
;WITH DeleteThese AS (
        SELECT li.ComputerId, li.UserId, li.EventDateTime AS LoginEventDateTime, li.EventType AS LoginEventType, lo.EventDateTime AS LogoutEventDateTime, lo.EventType AS LogoutEventType, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY li.ComputerId, li.UserId, li.EventDateTime, li.EventType ORDER BY lo.EventType, lo.EventDateTime) AS rn
          FROM @EventLogs li
            LEFT OUTER JOIN @EventLogs lo
              ON li.ComputerId = lo.ComputerId
              AND li.UserId = lo.UserId
              AND lo.EventType IN (42,45,52)
              AND li.EventDateTime < lo.EventDateTime
         WHERE li.EventType IN (40,43,44,53,57)
)

DELETE e
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO @WorkTable
  FROM DeleteThese dt
    INNER JOIN @EventLogs e
      ON dt.ComputerId = e.ComputerId
      AND dt.UserId = e.UserId
      AND (
               dt.LoginEventType = e.EventType
           AND dt.LoginEventDateTime = e.EventDateTime
          )
       OR (
               dt.LogoutEventType = e.EventType
           AND dt.LogoutEventDateTime = e.EventDateTime
          )
 WHERE rn = 1
   AND dt.LogoutEventDateTime IS NOT NULL;


SELECT *, 'These are rows left in the table.'
  FROM @EventLogs;

SELECT *, 'These are rows removed from the table, and ready to be processed.'
  FROM @WorkTable;
```

Now the rows are deleted from the original table, but we have them in a table variable (remember this will only persist for the duration of the execution)

```
ComputerId                              EventDateTime               EventType   UserId                                  (No column name)
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:49:50.0000000 53          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are rows left in the table.
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:49:50.0000000 43          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are rows left in the table.
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:49:54.0000000 44          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are rows left in the table.
```

```
ComputerId                              EventDateTime               EventType   UserId                                  (No column name)
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:37:33.0000000 42          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are rows removed from the table, and ready to be processed.
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:00:54.0000000 43          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are rows removed from the table, and ready to be processed.
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:00:54.0000000 53          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are rows removed from the table, and ready to be processed.
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:37:41.0000000 43          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are rows removed from the table, and ready to be processed.
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:37:41.0000000 53          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are rows removed from the table, and ready to be processed.
060BA6D9-4A58-4186-BB89-369FC56AE674    2022-12-31 00:37:55.0000000 52          B2283380-6A52-492B-9617-5D4B202DA8A1    These are rows removed from the table, and ready to be processed.
```

Does this get you close to where you needed to be?

Comment: It definitely helped. These two answers worked nicely together.

Comment: The "DELETE e
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO @WorkTable" part performs very slow on large data set even with indexes. Any way to improve it?